lld cannot find -lgtest -lgtest_main
My environment is wsl2 Ubuntu22.04 LTS, compiler is clang-18.1.8, ld is LLD 18.1.8
However, when I compile my program, the ld output:
: && /usr/local/bin/clang++ -fPIC -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O0 -ggdb -fsanitize= -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls   -shared -Wl,-soname,libllama.so -o /home/gx/project/mlsys/KuiperLLama/lib/libllama.so CMakeFiles/llama.dir/kuiper/source/base/alloc_cpu.cpp.o CMakeFiles/llama.dir/kuiper/source/base/buffer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/llama.dir/kuiper/source/tensor/tensor.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib  /usr/local/lib/libglog.so.0.8.0  -lgtest  -lgtest_main  -lpthread && :
ld: error: unable to find library -lgtest
ld: error: unable to find library -lgtest_main
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

The lld can find libglog.so , but cannot find libgtest I donot to solve the problem
My CMakeLists.txt like this
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
find_package(glog REQUIRED)
find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
add_library(llama SHARED ${DIR_BASE} ${DIR_TENSOR})
target_link_libraries(llama glog::glog gtest gtest_main pthread)

The cmake configuration output like this:
Found GTest: /usr/local/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfig.cmake (found version "1.15.0")

I use the linux command ls /usr/local/lib | grep "libgtest", the output are:
libgtest.a
libgtest.so
libgtest.so.1.15.0
libgtest_main.a
libgtest_main.so
libgtest_main.so.1.15.0

And I install the googletest and glog from the source code

/usr/local/lib doesn't seem to be considered as a library search path in your build environment.
As for the Quickstart: Building with CMake,
target_link_libraries(llama glog::glog gtest gtest_main pthread)

should be
target_link_libraries(llama glog::glog GTest::gtest_main)

GTest::gtest_main will link to the both gtest and gtest_main.
Note, pthread is not needed in modern C runtime, this is just an empty library.

Thanks, I use this way to solve this problem
